# How does an ROR app pick which View to use during the return trip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Currently taking the intro to ROR on CodeAcademy, and the flow so far:

1. Create ROR App,
2. Modify Controller by creating a method inside the PagesCotnroller class.
3. Modify the Routes to point the 'welcome' request to 'pages#home' controller/method.
4. (Here's where I get confused, they say: Ok, now it's time to mod the View (home.html.erb)... find it in folder x/y/z. But where in this flow does this project specifically chose the home.html.erb file vs. another view. Granted for this test project there is no other view file in the folder, but what if there were 20 of them? I see steps 2 and three connected in the code, what about 4?

This may seem like a rudimentary question, but I rather understand now then move forward without having a clear core foundation.

Course link: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-rails/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Rails will look for a view in the controller name specified in the routes which has a same name as that of the controller action.

So you had **home action** under **Pages** controller, which will result in Rails going to home action and then based on your code within the action it will render a view.

But you can always specify which view you want to render within the controller action. Its preferable to have a similar name as it avoids confusion in the future.

```
PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if five_min_window_is_still_open_after_creation?
      # you need to have app/views/pages/show_with_edit.html.erb
      render 'show_with_edit'
    elsif timeup?
      # you need to have app/views/pages/show_without_edit.html.erb
      render 'show_without_edit'
    # else 
      # it will render app/views/pages/home.html.erb
    end
  end
end
```

You can render a *completely different view* also in the home action of `pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
  # renders app/view/books/home.html.erb
  render 'books/home'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

By convention. You can even just do:

```
# config/routes.rb
get `welcome`, to: 'pages#home'

# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController
end

# views/pages/home.html.erb
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Since rails is driven by a philosophy of [convention over configuration](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-that-Ruby-on-Rails-favors-convention-over-configuration) it can assume that the view is located in `pages/home.html.{erb|slim|haml}`. If the view cannot be found there it goes up a lookup tree and looks for `views/home.html.{erb|slim|haml}`. In this case `ActionController::Base` will just render the view even if there is no action in the controller.

Comment: but why home.html.erb as opposed to say tst.html.erb? Does the name of the view have to be the same as the name of the method in the controller?

Comment: No what really matters is what route is matched - in this case when you get `/welcome` the route would matches an action called `home` in `PagesController`. If the method exists it will be called. Otherwise rails will just to to find a view. If the method exists but is empty rails will also just assume that you want to render `home.html.erb`. You can render any view explicitly though.